# Python3 bytes to string with real hex bytes

Tags: python-3.x, string, hex, binascii

I've seen a lot of posts about this subject but I haven't found the solution I'm looking for (despite lot of attempts ...).
In a nutshell, when migrating one of my libraries from Python2 to 3, whose main data model is based on hex strings like this '\xaa\xbb\xcc' (string length=3) I've encountered the (by now) known issue with the usage of binascii.a2b_hex('aabbcc')  function, which gives   '\xaa\xbb\xcc' in Python2  and b'\xaa\xbb\xcc' in Python3.
Being the whole library based on this data model, including external libraries using it, it will take a lot of time to review the code line by line to migrate it to the bytes data model.
In conclusion, I'm looking for a Python3 function doing the translation, i.e.
b'\xaa\xbb\xcc'   -> '\xaa\xbb\xcc' (string length=3)
or
'aabbcc' -> '\xaa\xbb\xcc' (string length=3)
many thanks in advance!

tried all hex()/binascii.hexlify()/format

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `latin-1` codec which maps bytes to Unicode characters one for one, with the same values.

```
x = b'\xaa\xbb\xcc'
x = x.decode('latin-1')
```

Comment: this looks good: x='ª»Ì'  it remains to provide the hex representation (with len=3).

Comment: @Robby that's a different question.  You want to convert your 3-character string to a 12-character string as you print it.  I'm sure there's an easy way but I don't know what it is.

Comment: indeed the .decode()/.encode() with the 'latin-1' coding does the magic for the bytes <->string (same length) conversion, and then for a pretty printing/input better to avoid binascii.a2b_hex()/b2a_hex() all in all  and use bytes.fromhex()/hex() , i.e. the b'\xaa\xbb\xcc'  <-> 'aabbcc' conversion. thank you!

Comment: @Robby I didn't think `hex()` would work for you since it didn't include the `\x` parts, I'm glad you found something satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution that uses the re module to achieve the same result:

```
import re

def bytes_to_escaped_hex(input_data):
    if isinstance(input_data, bytes):
        hex_string = ''.join([f'\\x{byte:02x}' for byte in input_data])
        return hex_string
    elif isinstance(input_data, str):
        hex_string = re.sub(r'(..)', r'\\x\1', input_data)
        return hex_string
    else:
        raise ValueError("Input must be bytes or hex string without '0x' prefix")

# Examples
bytes_data = b'\xaa\xbb\xcc'
hex_string = 'aabbcc'

escaped_hex1 = bytes_to_escaped_hex(bytes_data)
escaped_hex2 = bytes_to_escaped_hex(hex_string)

print(escaped_hex1)  # Output: '\xaa\xbb\xcc'
print(escaped_hex2)  # Output: '\xaa\xbb\xcc'
```

Comment: same comment as in the previous answer